# How do I load images from url to show in UITableView?

Tags: swift

I'm loading json data from webservice using Alamofire, one of my request return a json like this:

```
"lorem ipsum...",
"http://site.ed/image.jpg"
```

Then I create a `var texto: [String] = []` to receive all texts.

Now I need to adapt to receive image to show in UITableView

### What I already do:

```
func loadPosts() {
    let url = "http://site.ed"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                let post = JSON(value)
                for (_, subJson) in post {
                    if(self.verifyUrl(subJson.stringValue)){
                        print("Valide URL \(subJson.stringValue)")
                    }
                    self.texto.append(subJson.stringValue)
                }
            }
    }
}

func verifyUrl (urlString: String?) -> Bool {
    if let urlString = urlString {
        if let url  = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            return UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

In this `print("Valide URL")` i need to  get the real image and put into a table, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try some image library like [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

What you need to do is just set imageView with url

```
imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://your_image_url.png")!)
```

Comment: Hey , I Just download the KingFisher from cocoapods and import the  KingFisher library and follow the rules but  i got a error u know that is ? is that `use of unresolve identifier imageView` what i need to do ?

Comment: Now i create a `let imageView : UIImageView` but still resulting a erro called `ambiguos reference to .kf_setImageWithURL`